# version control for Oracle 10g Express

Tags: oracle, version-control, concurrency, oracle-xe

I'm looking for version control for Oracle 10g.

can anyone suggest good ones (free and commercial ones) ?

Comment: It's not clear (to me, anyway) exactly what you're looking for with this question so I'm leaving this as a comment - you can use any source control system to store Oracle object DDL (e.g. tables, stored procedures, etc).  If you're talking about a system that is Oracle-specific and offers comparison and deployment functionality then one option is the Oracle Change Management add-on to your Enterprise license ($$$$ required)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://oracle-ddl2svn.googlecode.com 
Set of tools for automatization storing of oracle DDL schema in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Spectrum SCM](http://www.spectrumscm.com/) to store .SQL files of each database object (no table defs or data). We have spent a ton of time on the what, where and how. Two hard lessons that we learned were:

1) Chose a tool to create and update the files(we use TOAD) and stick with it. (We used three different tools before we settled on TOAD )

2) Make the version control part of the development process (otherwise you will get out of sync)

Comment: same with us, but SVN (and TOAD)